# How to execute C# code in visual studio code on a mac

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio-code

I've decided to try to learn to code in C#, mostly due to the fact I want to try my hand at deving games in the distant future. However, I now use a Macbook, and so I figured I should use VS Code. However I am unsure of how to actually execute the code once it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can inspire from this tut http://zablo.net/blog/post/run-and-debug-asp-net-core-rc2-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Instructions are fairly vague, given this is meant for Ubuntu, there isn't much I can take from this.

Answer (score 0):

C# execution is an add-on to the latest version of VS code. Go to the add-on tab, then search 'c#'. Install the first item on the list.

 You can also consider using Visual Studio for Mac, which has C# built-in.